# How to keep a reference of AsyncTask while orientation changes

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I am starting an AsyncTask from portrait orientation, Then I changed orientation into landscape. In this moment I need reference of that running AsyncTask so that I can cancel that task.

This is the situation actually:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.startBtn:
            sampleTaskOne = new SampleAsyncTaskOne(this, sampleTaskCallbacks);
            sampleTaskOne.execute();
            break;
        case R.id.stopBtn:
            sampleTaskOne.cancel(true);
            sampleTaskOne = null;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

Right now after orientation changes if I click **stopBtn** NullPointerException occured because **sampleTaskOne** is not initialized. So how can I keep a reference of running AsyncTask ?

**Please don't use Fragment. Don't mention it as a duplicate of "How to use asynctask while orientation changes" or something like that. I know several alternative solutions but I exactly want to keep reference of that AsyncTask.**

Answer (score 0):

You can store `sampleTaskOne` as static variable and pass it `null` when it was finished or canceled.

Comment: what if I need to track several async tasks ?